# Hive ql Driver how to specify database name other than default

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I am writing a sample program to connect to Hive metastore using org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver class. A sample snippet is as below

```
String userName = "test";
HiveConf conf = new HiveConf(SessionState.class);
  conf.set("fs.default.name", "hdfs://" + hadoopMasterHost + ":8020"); 
  conf.set("hive.metastore.local","false");
  conf.set("hive.metastore.warehouse.dir","/user/hive/warehouse"); 
  conf.set("hive.metastore.uris","thrift://" + hadoopMasterHost + ":9083"); 
  conf.set("hadoop.bin.path", "/usr/hdp/2.2.0.0-2041/hadoop/bin"); 
  conf.set("yarn.nodemanager.hostname", hadoopMasterHost);
  conf.set("yarn.resourcemanager.hostname", hadoopMasterHost);

  ss = new MyCliSessionState(conf);
  ss.out = new PrintStream(System.out, true, "UTF-8");
  ss.err = new PrintStream(System.err, true, "UTF-8");

  SessionState.start(ss);

  driver = new Driver(conf);
  query = "show tables";

if (userName == null || userName.isEmpty())
        return driver.run(query);

    UserGroupInformation ugi = createUgi(userName);
    CommandProcessorResponse response = ugi.doAs(new PrivilegedExceptionAction<CommandProcessorResponse>() {
        public CommandProcessorResponse run() throws Exception {
            CliSessionState ss = null;
            ss = new MyCliSessionState(conf);
            ss.out = new PrintStream(System.out, true, "UTF-8");
            ss.err = new PrintStream(System.err, true, "UTF-8");

            // refresh thread local SessionState and Hive
            SessionState.start(ss);
            Hive.get(conf, true);

            return driver.run(query);
        }
    });

    return response;
```

I am able to connect to **default** database and get list of all tables. But how can I connect to other databases (other than **default**) ? I tried searching hive configuration property, but could not found one to specify database name. Can somebody help me please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you want to do things the hard way, and re-implement the Beeline utility. For most people it would appear to be a masochist attempt, but who am I to judge?

Anyway, at this point you **have to** execute HQL commands, like anyone else... and anyone should know about the "use" command:

```
driver.run("use " +argDatabase) ;
// check status
driver.run("show tables") ;
// check status, parse output
driver.run("describe extended " +argTable) ;
// check status, parse output
```

Comment: I tried running "use sample" query. The response was successfull.  But "show tables" query still gives me table list of default database. Is there anything I am missing, like any hive configuration parameter need to change?

Comment: Are you using the *same* session for both commands, not re-creating / re-setting / re-freshing anything in between?

Comment: Every query runs with in its own session. Should I run in same session?

Comment: I invoke the above code in a method each time for every query.

Comment: Metaphysical question: what do you think a **session** means?

Comment: Thanks @Samson, it worked after running both the queries in one session .